# Create re-usable function that can work with mutliple repetive classes and ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I am creating a web app that will do comparisons for products on the same page. Each time a person adds a new product they have the option to adjust some of the input fields. Each product has the exact same attributes such as the class and name. I may be able to append something on to each ID but there is a good chance that as each form is added to this page, it could possibly have a repeated ID. Yes I know that is not proper HTML but it works anyway. So my question is that how would I be able to re-use this same function without having to have one for each specific form that is added?

I have a sample of what I would be doing here:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="the_input_id" class="formField1" placeholder="formField1">
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1" class="formField2" placeholder="formField2">
<input type="text" id="total" class="total" placeholder="total">
</form>

<form>
<input type="text" id="the_input_id" class="formField1" placeholder="formField1">
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1" class="formField2" placeholder="formField2">
<input type="text" id="total" class="total" placeholder="total">
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {

$('.formField1,.formField2').blur(function() {  
    updateTotal();
});


var updateTotal = function () {
  var input1 = parseInt($('.formField1').val()) || 0;;
  var input2 = parseInt($('.formField2').val()) || 0;;
      if(!input2){
          $('.total').val($('.formField1').val()) || 0;;
      }

      if(!input1){
            $('.total').val($('.formField2').val()) || 0;;
      }

  else {          
        $('.total').val(input1 + input2) || 0;;
  }
};

var output_total = $('.total');

var total = input1 + input2;

output_total.val(total);

 });
```

So basically, as each form is added, allow it to use that function and keep the outputs separate?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icweat/6E45k/1/)

Comment: use relative paths and feed your script the parent container of each.

Comment: If you don't have "proper HTML", then fix that first! "repeated IDs" do **not** work.

Comment: Could you expand on that please.

Comment: @isaacweathers: He says you simply should give your function a parameter on which form to act.

Comment: But I won't know how many forms may be created. So I would need a global reference for any of the forms that basically says when the user is in this form, use this function and display result here but ignore any other parameters which may have the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not 100% sure what your trying to do with the particular script, but i can see what you want to do in an over-all pattern sense.

something like this should work:

```
$(function() {

    $("form").on("blur", "input", function(e){
        updateTotal(e.target.form);
    });

 function updateTotal (root) {
    var input1 = parseInt($('.formField1', root).val()) || 0;;
    var input2 = parseInt($('.formField2', root).val()) || 0;;
        if(!input2){
            $('.total', root).val($('.formField1', root).val()) || 0;;
        }

        if(!input1){
              $('.total', root).val($('.formField2', root).val()) || 0;;
        }

    else {          
          $('.total', root).val(input1 + input2) || 0;;
    }


  var output_total = $('.total', root);

  var total = input1 + input2;

  output_total.val(total);

  }

});
```

the big idea is to pass a container to the function and use that container in all jQuery dom searches inside the function by passing it as a 2nd parameter to $, after the css selector.

EDIT: i made a better binder using $.on() to hit forms not yet added to the dom when this code is executed.

Comment: I tried with your example in my updated fiddle and it did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/icweat/6E45k/3/ maybe I am missing something but I see where you are going with it. Like they hinted at above, if I can pass any form on the page as a parameter and keep it separate then I should be able to re-use it and keep the data separate only only display the outputs in the input that has that class and is relative to that form. The original fiddle above shows what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: snap, didn't see the fiddle. you have some syntax errors in there i fixed on mine, and the IF is a little off, not sure what you want there, but this is closer to what you're getting at, an expandable solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6E45k/5/ (answer updated with same working code) i think the jQuery events could be better, but my jQuery is rusty.

Comment: That works exactly as I need for now thank you. I was over reading about OOP JS and Prototypes which is what I think I'll have to do but this should get me to where I need for now. Gave ya the points. Thank you.